# Drawing Sprites although Origin is offscreen Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite, spritebatch

I´m developing my first game in Libgdx.
I have a Orthographic camera which follow a ball jumping like "Flappy Bird". My spinning obstacles have the origin in the middle because they are "attached" to some box2d bodies.

My problem is that Spritebatch doesn't draw the sprites while the origin of the sprite is offscreen and it looks like the obstacle is "teleporting" when the origin is onscreen and the sprite is drawn.

How can i "force" Spritebatch to draw a sprite even if the origin is offscreen ? I can't change the origin to the edge down because I need the sprite to spin.

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: what do you mean by origin of sprite is offscreen ? please show what you have done yet ?

Comment: I found my mistake '-_- it was one if before drawing the sprite which was false every time when the origin of the sprite was out of the screen. With "offscreen" I mean that you can see only a part(or nothing) of the sprite on the screen  .  Thanks for trying to help me ! :)